# (Batch) How can I use two variables to refer to another variable in an IF statement?

Tags: variables, if-statement, batch-file

This is part of the code for a game I'm making.

```
:south
set "message=You take a step South"
set /a "posY=%posY%+1"    //Moves player down one tile
if "%p%posX%%posY%%"=="#" set /a "posY=%posY%-1"    //checks if the player has hit a wall. If this is the case, bring him back one tile.
goto renderMap
```

Assuming %posX%==1 and %posY%==3 I'm trying to get the program to read the IF statement as:

```
if "p13"=="#" set /a "posY=%posY%-1"
```

But nothing I've tried seems to work. I was wondering if anyone could show me a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET p13=#
SET posy=2
SET posx=1

SET /a posy=posy+1
CALL SET destsq=%%p%posx%%posy%%%
IF "%destsq%"=="#" (
  ECHO hit wall - ouch!&SET /a posy-=1
  ) ELSE (ECHO moved south.)
```

This is probably easiest.

note that what is CALLed is
`set destsq=`
`%%` - % escapes the special meaning of `%`
`p`
`%posx%` - evaluated as `1`
`%posy%` - evaluated as `3`
`%%` - % escapes the special meaning of `%`

so the result is
    set destq=%p13%

Note that `set/a` allows you to do operations without the `%` and also allows the form `set /a var+=something` to add %something% to var.

Of course,
    set /a var += something
    set /a var += %something%
    set /a var = var + something
    set /a var = %var% + something
    set /a var = %var% + %something%
    set /a var = var + %something%

all do precisely the same thing. Your choice about which style you use...

see

```
set /?
```

from the prompt for docco.

Comment: Hmm, see, this more advanced stuff I haven't really gotten into yet

Comment: I'm just getting a "ELSE( was unexpected at this time" error from this

Comment: There MUST be a space between `ELSE` and `(`. Also, the `) ELSE (` must be on the same physical line.

Comment: Ok, now `if "%destsq%"=="#" (` is being read as `if " " == "#" (`

Comment: So - destsq isn't being set, but you haven't said how either `destsq`, `posx`, `posy` or `p13` are being set. Make sure that there are no spaces in your `SET` statement arguments if you are not using `set /a`. `SET POSX = 1` for instance sets the value of the environment variable "POSX " to " 1" - including the spaces. Note also that TRAILING spaces on a line are also included in a `SET` - and they're a little hard to see (try `ECHO +%var%+` which shows the value surrounded by a very obvious character)

Answer (score 2):

If you are writting a game in Batch, then the speed of your program is important.

- There are three ways to use a variable as part of the name of another one: with `CALL` command, with `FOR` command, or using Delayed Expansion. `CALL` is the slowest one and Delayed Expansion the fastest.
- Always try to use the shortest way to write any command. The fastest way to increment a variabe is `set /A var+=1`.
- I strongly suggest you to use the standard array notation enclosing the subscripts in square braquets; this form is much clearer. You may read [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) for further explanations on this point.

Below is your same  code above, but including the previous points:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:south
set "message=You take a step South"
set /a posY+=1    //Moves player down one tile
if "!p[%posX%][%posY%]!" == "#" set /a posY-=1    //checks if the player has hit a wall. If this is the case, bring him back one tile.
goto renderMap
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is an simple example where you can see, how it works:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "posX=1"
set "posY=3"
set "p13=#"
set "pos=p%posX%%posY%"
if "!%pos%!"=="#" echo "#" found.
```

.. output is:

```
"#" found.
```

Comment: This just reads "!%pos%!" as !p13! rather than the value of %p13%

Comment: No, essential it reads the expanded `pos` variable. There are NO two variables `%pos%` and `!pos!` , it is all directed to `pos`. And it does read the value of `p13`, though.